# Display Post Meta in Header

Tags: post-meta, globals

I'm trying to get page post meta in my header so I can set some meta tags. I tried to get the global post variable but it only return true.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    global $wp_query;
    echo print_r($post);
    echo print_r($wp_query->post);
    die();
?>
```

All I get is `11` - is there a way to get my post meta in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_the_ID()`, the post object is not set up completely on `wp_head()`:

```
if ( is_singular() )
    $post = get_post( get_the_ID() );
```